# linear regression

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance

I am reading a paper and come across the following information:

```
 Predictor    Dependent Variable    R Square    Beta    P
     A                D                .12      .35   <0.05
     B                D                .16      .40   <0.05
     C                D                .13      .36   <0.05
```

Authors are using linear regression to compute the correlation between A and D, B and D and C and D, and they claim there is significant positive correlations between each and every one of them. I am confused and do not understand how can the authors draw such a conclusion with the presented data?

Comment: Which paper are you looking at?

Comment: @Glen_b it's http://www.fossati.us/papers/fossati-its08.pdf in Section 4 (evaluation) fourth paragraph last sentence

Answer (score 3):

The significance of the correlation between y and x is related to the significance of the coefficient in the regression of y on x.

Specifically, for the [usual t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution) on correlation under normality, they have the same p-value (they're said to be *equivalent* tests).

The conclusion that the correlation positive is based on the sign of the regression coefficient - in simple regression they have the same sign.

Comment: You mean the p-value is less than 0.05 so it's a strong correlation?

Comment: No; statistical significance does not imply the correlation is strong, just that it's not consistent with a population correlation of zero.

Comment: I guess I still not get what you mean. In this case how does the author conclude their claim? Because normally we look at R square, right?

Comment: My answer already explains how the correlations were concluded to be significantly different from 0 (that they're positive comes from the sign of the estimate of $\beta$). That covers the claim. That has nothing to do with concluding the correlation is strong, which was not mentioned in your statement of what they claimed. It's not clear to me where the difficulty lies.

Comment: You mean any positive value of beta will make the correlation significant?

Comment: Not at all. The claim you state in your question in effect consists of two parts: "the correlation is significant" (i.e. significantly different from 0) and "the correlation is positive". The first is established by the significance of $\hat\beta$. If it's not zero, it must be either positive or negative; we normally conclude that if it's different from zero it's because the population correlation makes the sample correlation further from zero than is consistent with it being zero. That the sample correlation is positive (rather than negative) second follows from the sign of beta.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18696/discussion-between-user1935724-and-glen-b).